# Flask RequestParser - accept dict and read key+value

Tags: python, flask, request, flask-restful

I am using flask_restful to create API that accepts JSON format data in format, i.e.:

```
payload = {'name' : 'test',
           'foo' : {'value135' : 10, 'value987' : 100}}
```

For parsing 'name', it's pretty straight forward with RequestParser().add_argument('name'). Problem comes with 'foo'. From 'foo' I need to parse all key's and value's, ideally as dict.

So far I tried using:

```
RequestParser().add_argument('foo', type=dict)
output: {"message": {"foo": "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"}}'

RequestParser().add_argument('foo', type=lambda x,y: (x,y))
output: '[["value135", "foo"], ["value987", "foo]]

RequestParser().add_argument('foo', type=lambda x,y: (x,y))
output: '{"message": {"foo": "\'ImmutableMultiDict\' object is not callable"}}'
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved ? Goal is to support current format of payload as it is.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try adding location='json' to add_argument?

Comment: Tried, but unfortunately does not work: `'{"message": {"svcs": "Missing required parameter in the JSON body"}}'`

Comment: Any luck? I'm a similar mess

Comment: Couldn't figure out in RequestParser so I switched to flask-rebar and marshmallow. This one allows using nested fields like: 
class TagsSchema(Schema):
    classification = fields.String()
    lock = LOCKED

and then: fields.Nested(TagsSchema, ...)